# Jenkins Pipeline Error when using Groovy as a Shell Command

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, groovy

I am running a simple startup trigger job using a Jenkins Pipeline Script with Groovy to enable CSS support and it gives me the following error.

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Jenkins-System/startup-trigger@tmp/durable-6b0ae7a3/script.sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
```

Below is my Pipeline Script...

```
pipeline {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yaml '''
            apiVersion: v1
            kind: Pod
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: groovy
                image: groovy:jdk8
                command:
                - cat
                tty: true
            '''
        }
      }
      stages {
        stage('Run Startup Trigger') {
          steps {
            container('groovy') {
              sh 'groovy System.setProperty(\"hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src \'self\'; img-src *; style-src \'self\' \'unsafe-inline\'; script-src * \'unsafe-inline\';\")'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `(` is a special character for the shell. quote or escape it

Comment: Also, `System.setProperty` only affects the process it's ran in (which is the groovy command in this case). It does nothing after the groovy command exits.